# How can I redirect a URL to an anchor link while maintaining the URL?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am building a one-page website which has multiple sections which I have implemented using a custom theme to display all my pages in one single homepage.

I would like the user to be able to navigate around the website by opening sections on the site. Doing so will update the URL using javascript pushState so the browser will show URLs of the form

```
website.com/about/
website.com/contact/
```

but I would like to add the possibility that the user can copy the URL for that page, and then when they type it in their browser, it will open the website and navigate them automatically to that page.

This is easy to do with javascript already with anchors. E.g. they can navigate to

```
website.com/#about
```

but I would like to use htaccess (or possibly Wordpress hooks) such that URLs of the form

website.com/$ are pointed to website.com/#$ while maintaining the first URL in the browser.

I have tried to add htaccess rules

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/|$) /index.php [L,NE]`

but when testing I see a 404 page.